# Azure AppService Kudu Deployment Fails on Push

Tags: node.js, linux, deployment, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I want to deploy a Web App (Node) to Azure App Services (Linux) over Kudu.

I followed the instructions and first tried it with Node 14 as the stack. The build processes crashed during make cause of some version problems I guess.
Now I have downgraded the stack to Node 12. When I try to push again I get this error:

`remote: hooks/post-receive: 4: hooks/post-receive: /opt/Kudu/KuduConsole/kudu.dll: not found`

Before the push worked fine and `npm` was triggered.

Any suggestions?
Edit:
When i try to start the Bash in Kudu i get this error
Kudu Error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bSVe.png)

Comment: It is recommended to use git for deployment. You can see details in `Action`.

Comment: Or you can run  `npm run build` command, then compress `dist` or `build` folder, deploy your web app with zip.

Comment: @JasonPan i use git for deployment , the push is successful but then the first remote message is the error above

Comment: This problem is very strange. I still used git to continue deploying the node program today, but I didn't see this error. Do you try the second way (zip)?

Comment: I think zpping would work but i need the automatic git deployment.

Comment: I know, then I can only suggest that you recreate a webapp, select a different area, and re-deploy using git. If the same problem still occurs, we can check the log. After the normal deployment and the prompt is successful, this problem will not occur. This problem is very strange, it is recommended to test it as I said.

Comment: Yes thats the last thing i want to try, because i can't recreate the Ressource myself. I checked again and what worked ist using kudu bash and then manually use npm intsall and  npm run build. , that worked Just the remote triggering seems not to work.

Answer (score 2):

When add /newui to the URL where you can reach Kudu you can start up a bash inside Kudu. From there you can delete `rm` everything inside the /home folder. After that a new push worked and also the deployment